# YouTube API V3 - How to get normalized game title?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get the *normalized game name* using ***youtube API*** for a video if it is in Gaming category.

For example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qIvWgSpy31k, for this video I can see its normalized game name is the description:

[image: normalized game name in description]

But when I use the `videos.list` method, I can not see this returned. After checking all the properties for the video, I can not find it either.

Is there any way to fetch the game name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That information isn't exposed by the YouTube API.  You can see that by checking the documentation for [Videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) which returns a list of [videos resources](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource-representation) this is the information available about a video.

You can request it as a new feature here [gdata-issues](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Enhancement%20Request)) why they are using a gdata forum for issues I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same problem, so far in 2020 they haven't implemented it yet. It looks more like business issue. The only way to get game title bound to video is webscraping. I've used headless browser library for Java called [HtmlUnit](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/htmlunit). When you go to the direct url of the video you want to scrape just get html from it and use the regex listed below to acquire game title.

```
(?<=,"title":\{"simpleText":").*?(?="},"subtitle")
```